# Maximise over functions in Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

Define the functions $h$, $j$, and $k$ that are each functions of 3 variables:

```
h[x,y,z]
j[x,y,z]
k[x,y,z]
```

How can I find the max of these functions? I want the answer to return the function which is the largest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a particular point `(x,y,z)` in mind:

```
MaximalBy[{h,j,k},#[x,y,z]&]
```

Comment: indeed for a particular point `(x,y,z)`. How can I also return the element in the set `{h,j,k}` that corresponds to the Maximum?

Comment: @Sid That's an entirely different question. Define `m[x_,y_,z_]:=Max[h[x,y,z],j[x,y,z],k[x,y,z]]` and then apply `FindMaximum`.